# Map table and views with Entity Framework CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, code-first

I have 1 table and 2 views (PeopleView and ProjectView) in my DB.

Table named Hours, has columns which are "references" to views.

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Date] [date] NOT NULL,
[PeopleId] [int] NOT NULL, // Reference to PeopleView
[ProjectId] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL, // Reference to PrijectView
[Hour] [int] NOT NULL,
```

I red that is not possible create forign key with view. So my question is how to create mapping for this situation in EntityFramework.

When I get some Hours entity from DB I want to access to Project entity like that:

```
hour.project.name
hour.project.id
```

It is possible ?

Hour Entity:

```
   public class Hour : Entity<int>
{
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }


    public virtual PeopleView People { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int? PeopleId { get; set; }


    public virtual ProjectView Project { get; set; } // How to access project object from hour object when Project is a View in DB ?
    [Required]
    public virtual string ProjectId { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Column("Hour")]
    public virtual int Hours { get; set; }


}
```

ProjectView entity:

```
[Table("ProjectView")]
public partial class ProjectView : Entity<string>
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Offer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do this. You can use the `ForeignKey` attribute/annotation to tell the framework how to build the relationships between your classes (even if there's not an actual foreign key in the database).

Something like this:

```
[ForeignKey("PeopleId")]
public virtual PeopleView People { get; set; }
[Required]
public virtual int? PeopleId { get; set; }


[ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
public virtual ProjectView Project { get; set; } 
[Required]
public virtual string ProjectId { get; set; }
```

Comment: After do this, is necessarily create new migration ? When I added this and try to access to property I got this error: {"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."}

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to create a migration since the views already exist in your database. Regarding the error, is it possible that you are disposing  your DbContext before accessing the navigation property? This is a common issue when using lazy-loading, especially with MVC - you may be disposing the DbContext in your controller but trying to access the property in your view.

Comment: Ok thanks, everthing i do in controller.I have not this problem when I use normal DB tables...

Comment: Hmm - it's hard to say without seeing the code. If you want to update your question with the controller code, I'd be happy to take a look.